# Finding the gradient of a variant of a total variation regularized least squares cost function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, image-processing, gradient-descent, total-variation

As the question states, given a sum-function :

$$f(x) = \sum_{ij}\left({\sqrt{(x_{ij} - y_{ij})^2+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x_{ij}-x_{i+1j})^2+(x_{ij}-x_{ij+1})^2 +1}\right)$$

where $x_{ij} $ describes the optimized  image , $y_{ij}$ the noisy image (assuming the images are presented as pixel-arrays) and the function describes an optimization's problem.

how to find the gradient of this function ?

I gave it already a try and my result is :

$$\nabla f = \sum_{ij}\left(\frac{x_{ij} - y_{ij}}{{\sqrt{(x_{ij} - y_{ij})^2+1}}} + \frac{2(x_{ij}-x_{i+1j}) + 2(x_{ij}-x_{ij+1})}{\sqrt{(x_{ij}-x_{i+1j})^2+(x_{ij}-x_{ij+1})^2 +1}}\right)$$

Is it right ? and given the following code for finding a the gradient descent how could i find the gradient descent ? what would my **curr_x** be (assuming $x = y$ in the beginning ) ?

Code :

```
cur_x =  # The algorithm starts at x=6
gamma = 0.01 # step size multiplier
precision = 0.00001
previous_step_size = 1 
max_iters = 10000 # maximum number of iterations
iters = 0 #iteration counter

df = lambda (function)

while (previous_step_size > precision) & (iters < max_iters):
    prev_x = cur_x
    cur_x -= gamma * df(prev_x)
    previous_step_size = abs(cur_x - prev_x)
    iters+=1

print("The local minimum occurs at", cur_x)
```

Comment: Do you really need the $ \sqrt{ \cdot } $ operation?

Comment: @Royi first part will be deleted actually but the second (after the +) is necessary

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @Royi we assume x=y at the start .. and if you look at  the function , the first part is the difference between x und y so it will be 0 and eliminated

Comment: I'm not talking about the derivative. I'm talking on the Cost Function. Could you use the Squared $ {L}_{2} $ norm instead of the norm itself?

Comment: @Royi i don't think so

Comment: Could you tell where did you get this objective function from? It is similar to Total Variation.

Comment: @Royi no, not since you point it out, it looks yeah the similar

Comment: Since I don't understand the origin and you won't share it I can't make a better form which will yield easier solution. All I can say is that you should validate your answer using Finite Differences.

Comment: @Royi its just a task was giving in one of the courses in my university, what i was interested in

Comment: First, the Sum bounds is different for the second term, so you need to take care of that. Second, when you derive with respect to $ {x}_{i j} $ pay attention it appears in 3 places in the second term. The way to do it is to validate your answer using Finite Differences.